# Search under file and folders with any file extension and move them to different folder

Tags: powershell

How do I search for files with certain extensions and move them to different folder using PowerShell?

Comment: Next time, please put some effort into solving this yourself before you post here and when you do, post what code you currently have and what about it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

The cmdlets that you're looking for are `Get-ChildItem` and `Move-Item`. You can read how they work by running `Get-Help Get-ChildItem -full` and `Get-Help Move-Item -full`